# Corelocation - ranging beacons while in car

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon

I am using `CoreLocation` to range beacons in my app.
I noticed a problem while entering the car and started driving.

Beacons are ranged, but the signal strength (derived from RSSI) is "jumping" - it's going from 0 (connection lost) to proper value. It forms a pattern in `didRangeBeacons:InRegion:` 1 readout proper, 1 connection lost.

What could cause the problem?
iPhone gets connected to onboard bluetooth (I have to perform more tests on it) and maybe bluetooth is "overloaded" or maybe `coreLocation` beacon ranging has problems while moving?

Comment: Is the beacon with you in the car? What frequency does the beacon broadcast with? Most beacon vendors all you to change the advertising interval—if yours does too, try lowering it.

Comment: Yes, the beacon is with me (otherwise I should be driving circles not to lost it. Beacon is self-made and I am unable to check the interval right now. I'll go back to question when I find this information.

Comment: Hi, I finally got the values: we had varying time interval from 100 to 500ms. After setting it to 100ms (stiff value) the problem still occurred. CoreLocation was sending didRangeBeacons:InRegion: with the same frequency as before.

Comment: The advertising interval doesn't affect the frequency with which didRangeBeacons gets called. However, if the beacon is broadcasting 10 times a second, instead of twice a second, the chance that ranging will pick it up grows.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it won't have influence on didRangeBeacons call interval. The problem, however, remains. Will try to ride&debug.

Comment: Hey there, did you solve this problem? I am experiencing similar problem with beacon monitoring. When I enter the car, my iPhone gets connected. It looks like didExitRegion gets called when there is a bluetooth phone call in progress. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I did not. My company said that this problem was not worth digging into. I will update the info as soon, as get any solution.